# Include Audio in MediaRecorder in Android

Tags: android, audio, camera, video-capture, mediarecorder

I have integrated camera in my android app to record a video thr mobile camera and save in sdcard. it works fine, but the saved 3gpp file has no audio attached. If i add the configurations for audio the the camera does'nt open, just a black screen is seen. This is my code:

```
if(camera == null) {
      camera = Camera.open();
  camera.unlock();
}
recorder.setCamera(camera);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/adtvworld.3gpp");
recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
recorder.prepare();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up audio source and encoder in a correct order. The exception you are getting is java.lang.IllegalStateException. Try following:

```
if(camera == null) {
    camera = Camera.open();
    camera.unlock();
}
recorder.setCamera(camera);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/adtvworld.3gpp");
recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
recorder.prepare();
```

This piece of code should be working well for you. Feel free to change the AudioEncoder to something else than AAC, although it is the most efficient for low kbps.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the audio source as well..
`recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);`

Comment: Wen i tried including AudioSource it opened a black screen, when i start recording it throws error message

Comment: It tells 'The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again'

Comment: That does not give much information. Can you provide the log messages from the logcat? You can use DDMS from eclipse or use the cmd line tool more info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html)

Comment: im not testing this with the emulator to use DDMS, im testing it in the actual android phone, i dnt have a emulator which ca record video.

Comment: DDMS is not limited to the usage with emulator alone, it is just a debugging tool which can be used to connect to your actual device as well. Please go through this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Comment: From the Android docs on recorder#setAudioSource: "The source needs to be specified before setting recording-parameters or encoders. Call this only before setOutputFormat()."